# Combine two JavaScript regular expressions into one

Tags: javascript, regex

### Background:

I'm using director.js to match routes, and using regex for different parameters.

### Problem:

Need to come up with a regex for a parameter which matches regex 1 while not matching regex 2 (I know it's bad design but there're various reasons which I have to do it this way)

1. `[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!\(\)'*]+`
2. `[a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?`

What's the best way of doing this?

### Update:

Thanks to gyre. I think something similiar to `(?![a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)(?:[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+)` is what I want, but it doesn't work when I tried in my application, using this regex in https://regex101.com/, it can still find a match for string "00Bxx0000025e1UEA" --> Bxx0000025e1UEA which I think the library was confused somehow. Is there anyway to update the regex to not find a match for "00Bxx0000025e1UEA" at all?

I have tried to add ^ and $ for the regex:
`(?!^[a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?$)(?:[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+)` but that's still incorrect.

Comment: What about this? [`^(?![a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+`](https://regex101.com/r/OAD9kh/1)

Comment: This will exclude strings start with the second pattern but have something afterwards.

Comment: If that is undesired then [add a `$` at the end](https://regex101.com/r/OAD9kh/2).

Comment: `^(?![a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+$` this? Does't work with this string 00Bxx0000025gVvEAIddfdafdsfsf

Comment: Yes, I added a link. If the exclusion must not work as exclusion if something else follows that pattern, then also include a `$` at the end of the exclusion pattern, just [after the question mark](https://regex101.com/r/OAD9kh/3).

Comment: @daily, are you saying the exclusion pattern should not occur *anywhere* in the input? I don't understand why you say it doesn't work for `00Bxx0000025gVvEAIddfdafdsfsf`, as it should match in my opinion, and it does.

Comment: @sln unfortunately the framework limits me to only provide one regex to match the string and return true or false, it doesn't let me know about the groups.

Comment: @daily - Really.. Never heard that one before. I deleted my commented regex since you've dismissed the idea. Good luck !!

Comment: @trincot I think your regex is sound, I didn't saw your last post when I replied you, I was saying the regex in my comment doesn't work. Director.js seems acting wierd when I have ^ or $ as part of the regx.. I think I will need to dig in their library to find out why.

Comment: OK, I still posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially looking for this pattern, which uses a negative lookahead to ensure that the match for `<first>` is not also a match for `<second>`:

```
/(?! <second> )(?: <first> )/
```

```js
var first = /[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+/
var second = /[a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?/

var third = new RegExp('(?!' + second.source + ')(?:' + first.source + ')')

console.log(third)
```

Comment: Voted this for code maintainability. You can separate parts of the regex by variables then combine it to the constructor RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "the string to test"
var re1 = "your first regex, [._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+"
var re2 = "your second regex, [a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?"

if(str.search(re1) != -1 && str.search(r2) == -1) {
    // your action
}
```

[`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/search) will return `-1` if there is no match

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match regex1 and not match regex2 then why can't you check as,

```
var isTrue = regex1.test(str) && !regex2.test(str)
```

Comment: thx, I think I didn't make myself clear enough in the original post, I need a single regex to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one regular expression like this:

```
^(?![a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(0[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]00)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?$)[._a-zA-Z0-9-%!()'*]+$
```

The part that you want to reject comes first between `(?!   )`, which means it looks ahead and will fail the match if that part matches.

The additional `^` and `$` will make sure the match is done at the start of the string up until the very end of that string.

The pattern that you do want to match is placed at the end, again with an additional `$` to prevent that other characters follow the pattern.

See it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OAD9kh/3)

Depending on your expectations, you might want to remove the first `$`. Remove it, if you also want to fail strings that have the exclusion pattern with some other characters following it. If however such suffixed characters make the string potentially acceptable, you should keep that `$`.